# Redirect stderr of an imported C DLL to an arbitrary file

Tags: python

Python version = 2.7, Windows

Hi,

My Python script uses a shared C library and I want to redirect the standard IOs of the script and the shared C library in a file as in the following example (limited to the stderr stream)

C shared library code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_print(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "This string isn't displayed\n");
}
```

The Python script:

```
import os, sys, ctypes

def test():
    parserDll = ctypes.CDLL("./titi.dll")           # my shared C library
    file_stderr_fds = os.open("./toto.txt", 777)    # file in which redirect the stderr
    saved_stderr_fds = os.dup(2)                    # Backup stderr
    os.dup2(file_stderr_fds, 2)                     # Redirect stderr to file
    print >> sys.stderr, "zozo"                     # Python test redirect for Python script --> Ok
    parserDll.my_print(None)                        # test for the shared C library --> KO

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

When I run this Python script, in the toto.txt file I read "zozo" (displayed from the Python script) but nothing from the shared C library. However, if I comment os.dup2() out, both strings are displayed in the console.
Why?
Aren't standard IOs the same for the Python script and the shared C library that is used? In this case, how can I redirect both to the same file?

Comment: I think the two stderr streams are different.So you should redirect both of them to the same file.

Comment: For fault isolation, I think I'd try redirecting from the shell. Comment out all your python code that duplicates file descriptors and all that stuff. Then, in a bash shell, run something like `python your-script.py 2&>errors.txt`. That will redirect stderr to the file 'errors.txt' at the shell level. Does that capture all the error text you expected?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now that's odd, but when the library is compiled with Visual Studio, the shell command works and redirects both to a file ; but when GCC does the work, the string from the DLL is not written ! In any case, I would really need it to work straight from the script without any shell command since it's intended to be used in a GUI...

Answer (score 0):

When I run your example in Linux, it works quite fine.

Most likely, Windows doesn't actually use POSIX file descriptors for its `stdio` implementation, and is thus unaffected by your changing them around. I can't say I know exactly how Windows' `libc` actually implements POSIX file descriptors, but it's probably just some compatibility layer for the POSIX compatibility functions on top of whatever Windows uses natively, and the `stdio` code probably doesn't use them at all.

It seems to me as a bit of a hack, anyway, to switch file descriptors around behind the back of `stdio`. I think you should probably use an explicit `FILE *` variable that your C functions can use for logging, that you switch around with an explicit call from Python, instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would welcome the idea of writing errors in a FILE* instead of stderr to use it, without stream redirection, in the python script but how could I do that ? Can a FILE* be retrieved directly in a file object of python ?

Comment: You may be able to construct a `FILE *` with ctypes, but I'm not sure. I'm not familiar enough with ctypes to say. Either way, you could certainly write a function in C that takes merely a pathname as a string and opens it, and call that function from Python.